# Encoding 1080p for DVD - Pr 5.5

Tags: video, premiere, cs5

When I encode my 1080 sequence using the MPEG2-DVD preset I get a slight letterbox effect on either side of the frame. Does anybody know if there is any way around that, or if that is just-the-way-it-is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1080 would suggest full HD, the rub is that DVD is not HD. At best DVD is 720 x 480 so I believe that PR5.5 like many other pro editors is scaling your 1080 to fit in this smaller screen format, so letter boxing would be expected.

Answer (score 0):

They are slightly different sizes. (I think it has to do with aspect ratio )

When I scale down 1920 HD to DVD I scale Fit Width,  not Fit all.
This scales it down but leaves a few pixels above and below.

I think you end up with 720x485 when it's supposed to be 720X480

Comment: That's what I've concluded too.